# How to read xml file up to a point so that I can write the same to another xml file later

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, .net-2.0

A lot of similar threads are not exactly what I want or they deal with Linq. I am using **.NET 2.0**

I have an XML file which is more like a template. I need to write XML to another file, but I need it to refer to the template XML file for the initial formatting.

**Like this:**

My template file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1#styling" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <styling>
      <style id="s1" tts:fontFamily="SchoolHouse Cursive B" tts:fontSize="16" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:textDecoration="none" tts:color="white" tts:backgroundColor="blue" tts:textAlign="center" />
      <style id="s2" tts:fontFamily="SchoolHouse Cursive B" tts:fontSize="16" tts:fontWeight="normal" tts:fontStyle="normal" tts:textDecoration="none" tts:color="yellow" tts:backgroundColor="black" tts:textAlign="center" />
   </styling>
  </head>
<body id="s1" style="s1">
  <div xml:lang="uk">
      <p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:04">Hi! </p>
      <p begin etc............</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</tt>
```

I need to read the first part up to `<p begin="00:00:00" end="00:00:04">Hi! </p>` (not including that line). I need to get into any .NET type so that I can pass that to a function which will write them to another XML file.

**Note: I dont want to read the template XML file node by node or element by element. I want a general solution as the initial part of the XML could be anything.**

I tried:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(templateFile);
var list = new Something(); //what type would be ideal
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.LocalName == "p")
       break;

    if (reader.LocalName == "")
       continue;

    list.Add(??); 
    //how do I read the rest here?
}
```

How will I be able to write the same?

Comment: why downvote? duplicate? not written well? or homework?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx#larg_topic3) is a great resource for this sort of thing.

Comment: @DavidBrabant I have written what I tried. To try further I do not know, hence the question. As I pointed out in the question, I am not asking for this specific solution. If so, I could have got the values like `reader.GetAttributes` etc. But I need a general solution, like which will read it to string or so even if there's no attribute at all for a node.

Comment: @RichardTowers ok thanks for the link. Could you tell me what is unclear?

Comment: What do you want as your output? All the XML up to the first `p` tag? Or an object representing it? Or something else?

Comment: @RichardTowers an object representing it. So that I can use it to write another XML file later.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to use an XML file in a way that is not XML-valid. No XML reader or tool will let you work with the unclosed `<body>` and `<div>` tags.

I would consider treating it like a text file, but then you are relying on the line-break formatting in the source.

Drawback is that you will need to continue using it as Text when writing stuff, but I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Henk, Its not at all unclosed. I have only given a part of it. Its really closed. I will make the edit

Comment: Still looks very much unclosed.

Comment: Henk, could you tell me what more is there to be closed?

Comment: The part up to `<p...>` has more open than close tags.